# How do RDBM’s make working with data more effective than flat files and spreadsheets

Tags: spreadsheet, rdbms, flat-file

Could anyone help me answer this question:

How do RDBM’s make working with data more effective than flat files and
spreadsheets.

Comment: Thank you the accepting of my answer. As you are over 15 reputation, you can also upvote the answers if you think they deserve it. It is a big reward to the answering person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are handling data in fixed-size blocks and indexing.